# How to convert an Oracle column value of datatype SDO_GEOMETRY to String which has ST_IsValid=false

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, oracle-spatial

Is there a function or a way to convert the `SDO_GEOMETRY` datatype to string in Oracle ?

`get_wkt()` doesn't work for `SDO_GEOMETRY` which are not well formed (`ST_IsValid=false`).

Comment: This looks a little specific compared to the tags you used for your question... This is not basic Oracle! Any tool or Google thing you use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to **write your own Oracle Function** `my_get_wkt()`, then use it as

```
update MY_TABLE set MY_COL = my_get_wkt(params);
```